# Delete items from the Admin Menu | OpenCart2.X

Tags: menu, opencart2.x

I am facing a really weird problem. I am trying to delete items from the admin menu. But it looks like the system does not even read that file no matter what I do, I get the same output !

The file I am working on is **admin\view\template\common\menu.tpl**

Here I tried to delete the whole menu except the dashboard and the catalog, but the output still the same, all menu items appears just find like I did nothing !

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li id="dashboard"><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> <span><?php echo $text_dashboard; ?></span></a></li>
  <li id="catalog"><a class="parent"><i class="fa fa-tags fa-fw"></i> <span><?php echo $text_catalog; ?></span></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $category; ?>"><?php echo $text_category; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $product; ?>"><?php echo $text_product; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $recurring; ?>"><?php echo $text_recurring; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $filter; ?>"><?php echo $text_filter; ?></a></li>
      <li><a class="parent"><?php echo $text_attribute; ?></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $attribute; ?>"><?php echo $text_attribute; ?></a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $attribute_group; ?>"><?php echo $text_attribute_group; ?></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $option; ?>"><?php echo $text_option; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $manufacturer; ?>"><?php echo $text_manufacturer; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $download; ?>"><?php echo $text_download; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $review; ?>"><?php echo $text_review; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $information; ?>"><?php echo $text_information; ?></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

this is the only logical thing to do ! What should I do now ?!

Comment: Have you installed any module works on `oc mod`? Try to clear modification cache and then check.

Comment: only ocmod can be reason for this strange behavior, did your have anything extra option in your menu or Openbay installed ? or you can check same file in your system > modification > your file path, to solve this you can regenerate modification after clearing cache form admin modification.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you. After I cleared the modification cache,it WORKED. Thank you again both of you Ved Pandya, and user5419232 for your replies.